# Bypass interaction requirement for navigator.getGamepads in Electron

Tags: electron, chromium, gamepad-api

I use electron for a robotics application, in which we have a custom joystick controller. This joystick has several buttons and knobs that have states that we show in our application (such as a speed dial 0-100%).

For security (fingerprinting) reasons, the [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API) does not show a gamepad as connected until the user interacts with it.

[image]

This however causes an issue with displaying the state of these buttons at startup. As a product where we control the users computer, the electron app and the joystick programming, this is not a security concern.

Are there any additional flags that I can set to ignore this behavior and see all gamepads on startup, regardless of if a user has pressed a button? Or has electron built a way to bypass this? I'm not having any luck finding anything.

My other option is to change our USB joystick code to just toggle a random button we don't use, to simulate it being pressed but this feels hacky.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Gamepad API. The [gamepad user gesture](https://www.w3.org/TR/gamepad/#dfn-gamepad-user-gesture) requirement is part of the Gamepad API specification and is not intended to be disabled or bypassed.

Try connecting to your custom joystick with [HID Explorer](https://nondebug.github.io/webhid-explorer/). If it works, consider [WebHID API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devices#webhid-api) as an alternative. With WebHID you can read the input report into a buffer, then parse the buffer to extract the values for each control.